# change the page title of subsites in sharepoint using C# code

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I want to change the title of the subsites in SharePoint using c#. Give me suggestion.

Comment: C# how? Webpart? Forms Application? What title? First you say Page, the subsite. This is not a tough question, by googling you get tons of information.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the sample code:

```
            using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://sp2010:90"))
            {
                foreach (SPWeb web in site.AllWebs)
                {
                    using (web)
                    {
                        web.Title = "New Title";
                        web.Update();
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: I also want to edit Url but if I am writing web.Url it's tell me Read Only then what to do..

Comment: Yes it is readonly property. You cant change it.

Comment: But I have to do it..Is there any way to do it programmatically??

Comment: Yes, use web.ServerRelativeUrl to set the new Url.

Comment: I have tried this but value of web.ServerRelativeUrl is not changed.

Comment: This should work. the code should update all subsites within site collection if (!web.IsRootWeb)
                        {
                            web.ServerRelativeUrl = "New URL";
                            web.Update();
                        }